# Install DeskJet 3762 on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: printing, hp

According to this:

https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/install/manual/distros/ubuntu

for 10.04 and above you need to do this to install printer support for a DeskJet 3762

`sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2 cups libcups2-dev cups-bsd cups-client libcupsimage2-dev libdbus-1-dev build-essential ghostscript openssl libjpeg62-dev libsnmp-dev libtool libusb-1.0-0-dev wget python-imaging policykit-1 policykit-1-gnome python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-dbus python-gobject python-dev python-notify python python-reportlab libsane libsane-dev sane-utils xsane`

However, this fails with:

```
Package python-imaging is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python-pil

E: Package 'python-imaging' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package python-qt4
E: Unable to locate package python-qt4-dbus
E: Package 'python-dbus' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package python-gobject
E: Unable to locate package python-notify
E: Unable to locate package python-reportlab
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It shouldn't need anything of that. Old tutorials are seldom useful. Just connect it and it should work. If not you may need `hplip`, that's all.

Comment: You are advised to read https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting and decide whether to struggle with HPLIP or use Ubuntu's official printing system.

Comment: And Ubuntu 20.10 is EoL. Please upgrade to a supported release before anything else.